# Not able to install Kendo UI Angular 2 dropdown control

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I am not able to install Kendo Ui dropdown for Angular 2. I have valid telerik credentials.  It is also to inform that other controls like "kendo button" can be easily installed: I am using below npm install  command.
Please help!

```
**npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns**

**Getting below error:**

npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-S" "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8

npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
npm ERR! <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
npm ERR! <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
npm ERR! <head>
npm ERR! <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
npm ERR! <title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
npm ERR! <style type="text/css">
npm ERR! <!--
npm ERR! body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
npm ERR! fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
npm ERR! h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
npm ERR! h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
npm ERR! h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
npm ERR! #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
npm ERR! background-color:#555555;}
npm ERR! #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
npm ERR! .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
npm ERR! -->
npm ERR! </style>
npm ERR! </head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Access is denied" error most likely happens if the scoped registry is not configured properly.

You should [go through the registry installation steps](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/#toc-add-the-progress-npm-registry) again. If you use a social login, make sure you have activated your profile, and have confirmed your e-mail. Depending on the terminal you are using, you may be required to write out your password (instead of pasting it) -- this has been a problem in Git Bash.

Comment: I am able to install Kendo button , kendo layout with npm. Also the command: "npm view @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns versions
" works properly. But I cannot install kendo-angular-dropdown. Please suggest?

Comment: Quite peculiar. It may be best to [open a support ticket](https://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets) and post more details, i.e. the output of `npm install @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns --verbose`

Comment: i tried again yesterday in another machine and it worked. Looks this whole npm private registry thing need to be tested by  Telerik in different scenarios and machines. In production, we will be using .npmrc file , if it does not work I will open the ticket. thanks anyways